# why not chrome back/forward button trigger popstate event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

window.history.replaceState({some JSON}, "tittle", aHref);

$(window).bind("popstate", function(){
alert("hello~");
});

});
```

When www.example.com page is firstly loaded, the above is executed. Then click a href in this page and another page is loaded. At this time, I click the back button in chrome and no alert "hello~" appears. But the page linked by aHref is loaded. 
Why?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the back/forward buttons to cause navigation, use `pushState`, not `replaceState`:

```
window.history.pushState({ "some": "object" }, "title", aHref);
```

The `pushState` method *adds* a history entry, whereas `replaceState` *replaces* the current history entry.

Comment: Sorry, I am a newcomer to front-end.

Comment: "replace" means deleting the current entry and pushing a new entry;
"push" means just pushing a new entry.
Is this right?

Comment: If I  neither pushState nor replaceState, is there a new entry added to the history?

Comment: Yes, that's right about replaceState. I'm not clear what else you're asking. History entries are added when you follow regular URLs or use `pushState`.